# Retrieve data of type Date from the DB with Postman

Tags: postman

I don't receive the value that I entered in my DB, when I get a response back from Postman. I make and `POST` Request with Postman and when I verify in my DB it's OK.

When I make a `GET` Request with Postman, the result of my request is an empty array and I don't know why.

Please need help!

Thank you.

/************* Model *************/

```
@Entity        
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)        
@Table        
public class RDV implements Serializable {        

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long idRDV;

@Column(nullable = false)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
@NotNull
private Date dateRDV;

private String nomRDV;
Getters and setters { ... }
```

/************** Controller ************/

```
@GetMapping(path="/rdv/getbydate/{dateRDV}")        
public List<RDV> getEventsByDate(@PathVariable("dateRDV")        
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date dateRDV)
{
    return rdvService.FindByDateRDV(dateRDV);
}
```

/*************** Service **************/

```
public interface RDVService {
List<RDV> getRDVs();

RDV saveRDV(RDV rdv);

RDV updateRDV(RDV rdv);

void deleteRDV (Long id);

List<RDV> FindByNomRDV(String nomRDV);

List<RDV> FindByDateRDV(Date dateRDV);
}
```

/************ Service Implementation **********/

```
@Override
public List<RDV> FindByDateRDV(Date dateRDV) {
    return rdvRepository.findByDateRDV(dateRDV);
}

/*********** Repository ***************/

@Repository
public interface RDVRepository extends JpaRepository<RDV, Long> {
List<RDV> findByNomRDV(String nomRDV);

List<RDV> findByDateRDV(Date dateRDV); }
```

[image: Postman]

What I'm expecting is the result of this request :

```
SELECT daterdv, nomrdv FROM RDV where daterdv LIKE '2018-06-20'
```

[image: Postman]